# Create a formatted string using SpEL with nested lists

Tags: java, spring-el

I have an object that represents and table and looks something like that:

```
public class Table {
   List<String> columnNames;
   List<List<String>> rows;

   // Getters and setters here
}
```

Let's assume I have a table that looks something like that:

```
  Name    |    City    |    User-id
====================================
  User1   |     NY     |     1
  User2   |     SF     |     2
  User3   |     CH     |     3
```

I'm trying to create a SpEL expressions that would yield something like this:

```
"(User-id: 1, Name: User1, City: NY), (User-id: 2, Name: User2, City: SF), (User-id: 3, Name: User3, City: CH)"
```

I'm able to create an expressions like this:

```
"'(' + Table.columnNames[0] +': ' + Table.rows[0][0] ...."
```

But I would like something generic where I don't have to hard code indices per row and instead can just concatenate this expression for every row, no matter how many rows there are.

Comment: Why not just add toString() to Table in Java?

Comment: @GaryRussell - I'm trying to provide this to non-dev (but yes-technical) users to define their own formatting to the data and I thought SpEL would be a good way to use an existing descriptive language instead of developing something like that myself.